# Android GridView scrolls into grid view

Tags: android, gridview, custom-scrolling

I have n number of gridviews that I want to be able to scroll into one another (I cannot have just 1 gridview because each gridview is likely to have different column dimensions). I plan to add each gridview in code to the LinearLayout, but as an example here is a sample xml layout.

```
<LinearLayout>
  <GridView />
  <GridView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Currently this just divides the screen in half into 2 grid views, which scroll separately.

I was hoping I could create a custom class that holds an array of GridViews and allows this continuous scrolling. Is that possible or is there a better way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having the screen split in several parts (GridViews) which independently scrolls is a very pleasant user experience, in my opinion.
Not to mention that if you will have a lot of GridViews, you'll need to put these GridViews in a ScrollView to allow the user scroll to the bottom of the page. And here is where the problems may begin.

Perhaps you should rethink the design. Did you consider using a ListView with a custom adapter instead?